# Transfer data from one TableView to another TableView by pressing the button

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, uitableview

transfer action data. The error is that I cannot reach the variable in the second TableView.

Error: Cannot assign value of type 'Fav?' to type '[Fav]' and Instance member 'getFav' cannot be used on type 'FavouriteTableVC'; did you mean to use a value of this type instead?

Struct Data

```
struct Fav {
    var image: UIImage?
    var name: String
    var price: String
    
    static let favName = ["Faaaak", "Dunc"]
    
    static func getFav() -> [Fav] {
        
        var favourites = [Fav]()
        
        for fav in favName {
            favourites.append(Fav(image: nil, name: fav, price: "29.000"))
        }
        return favourites
    }
}
```

first TableCell

```
class DivanCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    var fav: Fav?

    @IBOutlet weak var divanNameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var divanPhoto: UIImageView! 
    @IBOutlet weak var priceLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var sizeDivan: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var favButton: UIButton!
    @IBAction func favTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        favButton.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "heart.fill"), for: UIControl.State.normal)
        favTapped(favNext: FavouriteTableVC())
    }
    
    func favTapped(favNext: FavouriteTableVC) {
        fav = Fav(image: divanPhoto.image, name: divanNameLabel.text!, price: priceLabel.text!)
        FavouriteTableVC.getFav = fav // Error: Cannot assign value of type 'Fav?' to type '[Fav]' and Instance member 'getFav' cannot be used on type 'FavouriteTableVC'; did you mean to use a value of this type instead?
    }

}
```

second TableViewVC

```
class FavouriteTableVC: UITableViewController {
    
    var getFav = Fav.getFav()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var favName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var favPrice: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var favImage: UIImageView!

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        
        return getFav.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "favouriteCell", for: indexPath) as! FavouriteTableViewCell

        let favs = getFav[indexPath.row]
               
        cell.name.text = favs.name
        cell.price.text = favs.price
        cell.favImage.image = favs.image
        tableView.reloadData()
        return cell
    }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

// FavouriteTableViewCell

class FavouriteTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var name: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var price: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var favImage: UIImageView!

}
```

Comment: Instead of adding `favTapped` method in `DivanCell` add it to `ViewController` and you can use button `tag` property to identify index and get the data from array. then you can pass this information easily with navigation to `FavouriteTableVC `

Comment: my application logic is different. No need to pass through navigation, I have tabBarController

Comment: Format your code when posting it here, too much clutter. Also, where is `FavouriteTableViewCell` declaration?

Answer (score 0):

There are two bugs in the code that are causing errors.

`Cannot assign value of type 'Fav?' to type '[Fav]'` is caused as you are trying to assign an object of type `Fav?` to `[Fav]`.

`Instance member 'getFav' cannot be used on type 'FavouriteTableVC'; did you mean to use a value of this type instead?` is caused because you are trying to allocate variable without creating an object.

Replace with `favTapped(favNext: FavouriteTableVC)` method with the below code. Hope this fixes your problem.

```
func favTapped(favNext: FavouriteTableVC) {
    if let tempFav = Fav(image: divanPhoto.image, name: divanNameLabel.text!, price: priceLabel.text!){
       favNext.getFav = [tempFav] 
       fav = tempFav
    }
}
```

Comment: Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'Fav'

Comment: without condition, the error is still the same because of the array

Comment: Sorry. My mistake, forgot to save it as an Array. The answer has been updated. Check it once.

Comment: Noooooooooooooo